# select statement not working with variables, but does with fixed values

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

So i have this statement:

```
execute immediate  'SELECT count(*) INTO counter FROM (SELECT table_a.NUMBERWANG FROM table_a MINUS SELECT table_b.NUMBERWANG FROM table_b )';
```

But if i try and make one of the values into a variable, the statement seems to no longer work.

If it try

```
execute immediate  'SELECT count(*) INTO counter FROM (SELECT table_a.NUMBERWANG FROM table_a MINUS SELECT table_b.NUMBERWANG FROM ' || variable_1 || ' )';
```

I get the missing keyword error.

Where it gets unusual is if i remove the "INTO COUNTER" it will run.

Is it my placement of the INTO that is wrong or is it something else entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have an `into clause` inside the string you are executing.

You need to move this out of the string and tell the `execute immediate` to do that:

```
declare
  l_count integer;
  l_sql   varchar(4000);
begin
  l_sql := 'SELECT count(*) FROM (SELECT table_a.NUMBERWANG FROM table_a MINUS SELECT table_b.NUMBERWANG FROM table_b )';
  execute immediate l_sql into l_count;
end;
/
```

Comment: This worked thanks so much.

I had tried putting it into its own string before but i didn't think to put the into with the execute immediate. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can perform a `SELECT...INTO...` dynamically. When I try this:

```
DECLARE 
  counter  NUMBER;
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT COUNT(*) INTO COUNTER FROM TEST_TABLE';

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('COUNTER=' || COUNTER);
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error: ' || SQLERRM);
END;
```

I get `ORA-00905: missing keyword`. I can get rid of the error by removing the `INTO` clause, but then of course I still don't get a value into `counter`.

If you want to execute this sort of statement dynamically and be able to retrieve the value(s) into variables you'll need to use a cursor, as in:

```
DECLARE
  counter  NUMBER;
  c        SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  OPEN c FOR 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TEST_TABLE';
  FETCH c INTO counter;
  CLOSE c;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('COUNTER=' || COUNTER);
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error: ' || SQLERRM);
END;
```

Share and enjoy.

Comment: You don't need a cursor for this.

Comment: This worked by making two cursors one for table_a and one for table_b.